# Access to stored APNS Notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, apple-push-notifications, iphone-privateapi

Is it possible in iOS to access the stored APNS Notifications, regarding to my app, on runtime?

I know, I should use the **application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:** and/or the **application:didReceiveRemoteNotification** methods, but I want to read out the already stored notifications.

The app should not be published in the AppStore, so i could also use private APIs.

Best Regards, Patrick

Comment: Store them when you get them somewhere in your app bundle, and read them later.

Comment: unfortunately that is not an option. I would like to read out also unopened push-notifications